# send email with django

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to configure my email to send an automatic email but whenever I do with my non-google email it gives an error. 
 But when I set up email google accept send I tried to contact my domain hosting team but so far I have no solution for the problem

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.visaogis.co.mz'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'baptista@visaogis.co.mz'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******************'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'`enter code here`
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'baptistaguivala@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*************'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `gmailapi_backend` (https://pypi.org/project/django-gmailapi-backend/)?
Otherwise, you can use `SendGrid` (https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/django).